# Way to update Fragment's UI after state changes

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to reuse the same Fragment simply swaping some instance variables in the Fragment. My problem is that I can't force the UI to update. I tried:

```
detailFragment.setDetails(bundle);
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.detailFragment, detailFragment);
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
ft.commit();
```

but it doesn't seem to make any changes to my UI. At the same time when I create a new DetailFragment() the same code works fine and changes UI. Could you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to update the 'views' in your fragment. You can get the views and set their new values. EG: If it is a textview, you simply set the new text.

Answer (score 0):

you have your `detailFragment` which I am assuming the your fragment class.

keep an instance of that class

```
DetailFragment df = (DetailFragment)detailFragment;
```

create a public method in that class

```
public void updateMyUi(){
    //do ui stuff
}
```

then all you have to do is call is

```
df.updateMyUi();
```